# ArrayList of Arrays gets overwritten everytime

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I'm trying to use ArrayList in a recursive function.
I'm trying to find the combinations of the array arr of size r. Like if I have an array

```
["A","B","C","D"]
```

I want to print :

```
A B C
A B D
A C D
B C D
```

But when I print my ArrayList in the recursive function it gives:

```
Call1 : ABC
Call2 : ABD
        ABD
```

And so on. ie every time the previous contents of the `ArrayList` are overwritten with the new content and the new content is also added to the end.
Also in the Function calling the recursive function my ArrayList is not returned it just contains a list of Es.

In the function calling the recursive function I have something like

```
private static void combine(String[] arr, int r) {
    String[] res = new String[r];
    ArrayList<String[]> result = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    doCombine(arr, res, 0, 0, r, result);
    System.out.println("\nIn main" + result.size());
    for (Object[] array : result) {
        for (Object o : array)
            System.out.print("item: " + o);
        System.out.println();
    }
}

// This recursive function finds combinations
private static void doCombine(String[] arr, String[] res, int currIndex,
  int level, int r, ArrayList<String[]> result) {

    if (level == r) {
        printArray(res);
        String[] inter = new String[r];
        inter = res;
        result.add(inter);
        // Tryinh to see wht the array list has every time
        for (Object[] array : result) {
            for (Object o : array) {
                System.out.print("item: " + o);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        inter = null;
        return;
    }
    for (int i = currIndex; i < arr.length; i++) {
        counter.add();
        res[level] = arr[i];
        doCombine(arr, res, i + 1, level + 1, r, result);
    }
}
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Edit: I do not know the size of combinations I need. i.e here I gave example for 3 I may need for 2 or 4 or 5

Comment: Edit 2: Here is my printArray()     private static void printArray(String[] res) {
        for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(res[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
       
    }

Comment: Edit 3: I created a class counter just to count the number of combinations found. here is the code for that:class variable
{
public int count;
variable(int a)
{
this.count = a; 
}
public void add()
{
this.count ++; 
}
public void print()
{
 System.out.println("Counter is "+this.count);
}
}

Comment: What was the purpose of your last edit? I rolled that back, because the removed semicolon would cause a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code

```
    String[] inter = new String[r];
    inter = res;
    result.add(inter);
```

to

```
        String[] inter = new String[r];
        int k=0;
        for(String s:res){
            inter[k] = s;
            k++;
        }
        result.add(inter);
```

And the code work as Expected.

Output:

> 1
>
> A B C
>
> 2
>
> A B C
>
> A B D
>
> 3
>
> A B C
>
> A B D
>
> A C D
>
> 4
>
> A B C
>
> A B D
>
> A C D
>
> B C D

Comment: Gosh, don't reinvent the wheel: [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int))

Comment: Accept the answer if your problem solved so that  this question will not display in unanswered section.